# Input Field not coming when using .val() in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a simple jquery and php program which is checking username availability. But when i am running this code it is not showing the input field.
Here is my jquery

```
<html>
<head>
<title>the title</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" 
   src="js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#check').html(username);
    $.post( 
        "user_availability.php",
        { username: $("#username").val()},
        function(data) {
            $('#check').html(data);

        }
    );
});
   </script>
</head>
<body>

   <div id="check">

   </div><br><br>
<form>
 <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="rajan" /></form>
</html>
```

Please help me out as i am a beginner to jquery.

Comment: Any error on line- `$('#check').html(username);`

Comment: are you want to display when input box typed?

Comment: Yes i want that when some when type text in the input field it sends the data and receive it

Comment: You're calling `$.post` when the page is first loaded, you're not waiting for the user to enter anything.

Comment: SO can you tell me how should i correct this

Comment: @user3647254 check with my answer it send data when input typed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `Username`,Using `keyup` method send the data and get the result

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var username = $("#username").val();
    $('#check').html(username);
    $('input:text').keyup(function () {
        $.post(
            "user_availability.php", {
            username: $(this).val()
        },
         function (data) {
            $('#check').html(data);

        });
    });
 $('#username').trigger('keyup');//if you want to trigger keyup onload add this
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sridhar R for the answer. Now my program is working well

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var username = $("#username").val();
    $('#check').html(username);
    $.post(
        "user_availability.php", {
            username: username
        },
        function (data) {
          $('#check').html(data);
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: You can simplify further : `{ username: username},` +1

Answer (score 1):

username is

> not

defined

while trying to pass as an argument

```
$('#check').html(username); // <---
          $.post( 
             "user_availability.php",
             { username: $("#username").val()},
             function(data) {
                $('#check').html(data);

      });
   });
```

and if you want to check everytime the input changes, 
you need to listen to it

```
//keyup to check every time a character is entered
$('#username').keyup(function () {
        $.post(

// on change, to only check when user blurs the field
$(document).on("change","#username",function () {
        $.post(
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#check').html($("#username").prop('value'));
      $.post( 
         "user_availability.php",
         { username: $("#username").val()},
         function(data) {
            $('#check').html(data);

  });
```

});